# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Thrown Due To Foreign Key Relationship Apparently Not In Query

Tags: linq-to-sql

#### Overview

This is a strange error which has not googled well.

I attempt to create and insert an AssetOwner record.  But I receive the error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" due to a foreign key relationship on two tables that (apparently) have nothing to do with the SQL statement I'm attempting:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Adjustments_AdjustmentProcesses". The conflict occurred in
>   database "TPS_2", table "dbo.AdjustmentProcesses", column 'ID'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

#### Details

Here is the code snippet where the error is thrown (indicated by the comment) ("da" is just like a repository):

```
var add = new AssetOwner()
{
   Client = da.Clients.Get(adjustment.ToClientID),
   Asset = da.Assets.Get(adjustment.AssetID),
   StartDate = adjustment.EffectiveDate
};
da.AssetOwners.Add(add);

var remove = da.AssetOwners.GetCurrentOwner(da.Assets.Get(adjustment.AssetID));
remove.EndDate = adjustment.EffectiveDate;
da.SaveChanges(); // Exception here (this is DataContext.SubmitChanges())
```

A small picture of the tables and relationships relevant here:

[image]

The relationship throwing the error has been highlighted red, the table in question has been circled in red - as you can see, an insert of the AssetOwner doesn't appear to have much to do with the Adjustment-AdjustmentProcess relationship?

#### Troubleshooting

I'm using Visual Studio generated LINQ-to-SQL classes, and at times I've noticed strange gremlins in refreshed versions of my DataContext.  My first thought was therefore to delete the relationship in question, re-generate, re-create the relationship, re-generate.  This has not been successful.

I've stepped through the code a few times - it is notable there are no other SQL statements in the controller action before this one - and I have been unable to see any possible reason for this exception.  Nevertheless, I'll reproduce the entire controller action here (hoping the long code snippet won't discourage any potential readers):

```
public ActionResult ManualEntry(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        // Grab the adjustment process
        var process = da.AdjustmentProcesses.Get(id);

        // Map a dto and set the details needed for the view
        var dto = new AdjustmentProcessViewModel();
        Adapter.MapDto(dto, process, da);
        Adapter.SetDetails(dto, da);

        // Generate the premium values for those policies we can
        var pg = new PremiumGenerator(da);
        foreach (var apd in dto.AdjustmentPolicyDetails)
        {
            if (apd.CanAutoGenerate == true)
                pg.GeneratePremiumValues(dto.Policies[apd.Index]);
        }

        // Update the model from the form collection
        TryUpdateModel(dto.Policies, "Policies");

        // Run Validation
        var invalids = 0;
        foreach (var apd in dto.AdjustmentPolicyDetails)
        {
            var policy = dto.Policies[apd.Index];
            var validator = new PolicyValidator(da);
            validator.Validate(policy);
            if (!validator.IsValid)
            {
                invalids++;
                foreach (var ruleViolation in validator.RuleViolations)
                    apd.RuleViolations.Add(new RuleViolation(ruleViolation.ErrorMessage, "Policies[" + apd.Index.ToString() + "]." + ruleViolation.PropertyName));
                this.MergeRuleViolations(apd.RuleViolations);
            }
        }

        // If validation has failed, return the view
        if (invalids > 0)
            return View(dto);
        else // Otherwise process the adjustments
        {
            foreach (var adjustment in da.Adjustments.GetAdjustmentsForProcess(process.ID))
            {
                if (adjustment.ActionID == (int)AdjustmentAction.Add)
                {
                    var add = new AssetOwner()
                    {
                        Client = da.Clients.Get(adjustment.ClientID),
                        Asset = da.Assets.Get(adjustment.AssetID),
                        StartDate = adjustment.EffectiveDate
                    };
                    da.AssetOwners.Add(add);
                    da.SaveChanges();
                }
                else if (adjustment.ActionID == (int)AdjustmentAction.Remove)
                {
                    var remove = da.AssetOwners.GetCurrentOwner(da.Assets.Get(adjustment.AssetID));
                    remove.EndDate = adjustment.EffectiveDate;
                    da.SaveChanges();
                }
                else if (adjustment.ActionID == (int)AdjustmentAction.Transfer)
                {
                    var add = new AssetOwner()
                    {
                        Client = da.Clients.Get(adjustment.ToClientID),
                        Asset = da.Assets.Get(adjustment.AssetID),
                        StartDate = adjustment.EffectiveDate
                    };
                    da.AssetOwners.Add(add);

                    var remove = da.AssetOwners.GetCurrentOwner(da.Assets.Get(adjustment.AssetID));
                    remove.EndDate = adjustment.EffectiveDate;
                    da.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            var policyAdapter = new PolicyAdapter();
            foreach (var policy in dto.Policies)
            {
                var newPolicy = new Policy();
                policyAdapter.MapObject(newPolicy, policy, da);
                var validator = new PolicyValidator(da);
                validator.Validate(newPolicy);
                if (!validator.IsValid)
                    throw new Exception();
                else
                {
                    da.Policies.Add(newPolicy);
                    da.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Perhaps a clue is the fact that the object I'm working on is a "Transfer" (going down that code path) which throws the error, whereas an "Add" or "Remove" both work fine without throwing the error.  Still, the code is virtually the same, and all adjustment objects in the DB table satisfy the foreign key constraint.

To further aid troubleshooting, here is the stack trace:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement
>   conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Adjustments_AdjustmentProcesses". The conflict occurred in
>   database "TPS_2", table "dbo.AdjustmentProcesses", column 'ID'. The
>   statement has been terminated.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
>   lastResult)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicInsert(TrackedObject
>   item)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject
>   item)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
>   at TPS.Models.TPSDataAccess.SaveChanges() in
>   C:\Users\tim.niven.KJRG\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\TPS-trunk\TPS\TPS\Models\MainObjects\TPSDataAccess.cs:line
>   169    at
>   TPS.Areas.Clients.Controllers.AdjustmentProcessController.ManualEntry(Int32
>   id, FormCollection collection) in
>   C:\Users\tim.niven.KJRG\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\TPS-trunk\TPS\TPS\Areas\Clients\Controllers\AdjustmentProcessController.cs:line
>   257    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)

And so I've been banging my head on the table with this one all day - any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Tim.

Comment: have you tried a manual insert with pure sql to make sure your database is not the issue. Have you tried to regenerate your DBML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was silly in the end (as it often is): it was of course some other bit of code further up in the action, one of the adapter methods was manipulating an object retrieved from the database it shouldn't have been.

Once I isolated the code that was throwing the exception, and it worked, I changed the order of things, and found the exception was thrown not on the insert of the AssetOwner.  Therefore, I called DataContext.SubmitChanges() at numerous locations throughout the code to find out where it was causing the problem - found and fixed.